# Sheet music library

Tags: python, music-notation

I'm a python hacker looking to build a sheet music app.  I'm comfortable with reading/understanding sheet music (played piano for many years).  Here are my complete newbie questions..

Is there a standard for representing notes digitally?  I don't want to reinvent any wheels.

Given a sequence of notes and durations, is there a library for displaying these in a sheet music format?

Basically I'm looking for a place to get started.  I'm not heavily into graphics, so a existing open-source library would be awesome.  If none exists in Python, I'm competent at Java/Javascript/C as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Take a look at [lilypond](http://lilypond.org/). It uses LaTeX to typeset sheet music. Its input format is simple text, and can be generated pretty easily with Python or whatever.

[Abjad](https://abjad.github.io/) is a "Python API for Formalized Score Control" and a wrapper around lilypond, but I haven't used it and so can't vouch for it.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, [abc notation](http://abcnotation.com/) is [still](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_notation) the de facto standard text format in traditional/folk music circles.  There is [quite a bit of software](http://abcnotation.com/software) available for it, including [abctool](http://atte.dk/abctool/) and abc2ly (part of [GNU LilyPond](http://lilypond.org/)), both of which are written in python.  Being a self-described python hacker, I imagine you could turn either of these into a library without much trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not exactly what you're looking for, but there is a commercial program called [capella](http://www.capella-us.com) (from a small German software company; there is an English version, too). It supports the [MusicXML](http://www.recordare.com/musicxml) format, and it uses Python for scripting, so you can write scripts for extending its functionality (which is already quite impressive, though).

I learned Python because of capella. (Turns out I never did write any scripts for capella - never needed to - but it sure made me curious about Python :))

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a standard for representing
>   notes digitally?

I assume you've heard of [MIDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_Instrument_Digital_Interface) (which encompasses far more than simply notes and durations, but which is a standard that represents notes digitally).

I recommend looking at the Music Notation programs listed in the [Python in Music](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic) Python wiki page and seeing if you can extend or contribute to those applications before rolling your own.